# How to read R program P-Value for Logistic Regression

Tags: r, logistic

[image]

I'm not used to that kind of p-value form as I don't know how to interpret it...

It's usually shown a p-value with stars (significant codes) on its sides

Can anyone help? How to read if the variable significant or not...?

Comment: Start by taking a look at `str(myModel)` and `str(summary(myModel))`.

Comment: Also look at this link : http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/logistic-regression/significance-test-logistic-regression

Answer (score 1):

It would show star if the p-value is small enough, <0.05 or <0.001. P-value here gives you likelihood of zero-value parameter. Statistically speaking, null hypothesis is parameter of variable being zero, and p-value is under this hypothesis, the probability of large z occurs. With such high p-value, we cannot reject this null hypothesis. So from the Z-value and P-value in your model, there are no variables with significant impact.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer, I checked the variables again and turns out the _salstotalaktiva_ is the problem somehow